# Don't want limit on top of varprojlim

Tags: math-operators

When in displaystyle mode, using `\varprojlim_{i \in I}^{1}` gives

[image]

However, I want to look more like

[image]

The above can be obtained by `{\varprojlim_{i \in I}}^{1}` but I was wondering if there's some way to create a command (say, `\limit`) such that `\limit_{i \in I}^{1}` would give the desired result.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
    \varprojlim_{i \in I}^{1} \text{ vs. } {\varprojlim_{i \in I}}^{1}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want that the subscript is centered on `\varprojlim`, without taking into account the exponent, so some measuring is necessary.

I suggest to use a different name, such as `\invlim` for the operator. I also provide a modified `\varprojlim` where the arrow is smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% use a smaller arrow
\def\varprojlim{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\leftarrowfill@\scriptstyle}}\nmlimits@}

\NewDocumentCommand{\invlim}{e{^_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \varprojlim\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
  }{%
    % measure the exponent
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th{}^{#1}\kern-\scriptspace$}
    \IfValueT{#2}
     {% measure the subscript
      \sbox\tw@{$\m@th\scriptstyle#2$}%
      % measure the operator
      \sbox4{$\m@th\varprojlim$}%
      \dimen@=\dimexpr(\wd\tw@-\wd4)/2\relax
      % typeset the operator
      \mathop{%
        \varprojlim\nolimits^{#1}
        % backup
        \kern-\wd\z@
      }\limits_{#2}%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@
        % the subscript doesn't overflow
        \kern\wd\z@
      \else
        \ifdim\dimen@>\wd\z@
          % no need to kern
        \else
          \kern\dimexpr\wd\z@-\dimen@\relax
        \fi
      \fi
     }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
x\invlim_{i\in I} M_i     \\
x\invlim^1_{i\in I} M_i   \\
x\invlim^1_{i\in IJ} M_i  \\
x\invlim^1_{i\in IJK} M_i
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This only works in display style. If requested, we can make it to work also in text style, with the subscript on the side.

The “x” in front is just used to show the correct spacing.

Comment: Thank you, this works too (after using `\usepackage{xparse}` as in the other answer). What would you say is the difference between the two answers? Is there any case where one works better than the other?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hfk8.png) to see the visual comparison; left column is my proposal, right column is David's.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I'd do this but you could use the `\NewDocumentCommand` `e` argument type.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\oldvarprojlim\varprojlim
\RenewDocumentCommand\varprojlim{e{^_}}{%
  {\oldvarprojlim\IfNoValueF{#2}{_{#2}}}\IfNoValueF{#1}{^{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
    \varprojlim_{i \in I}^{1} \text{ vs. } {\varprojlim_{i \in I}}^{1}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to give many errors due to line 5 (`\RenewDocumentCommand`). The first one being: Undefined control sequence. [\RenewDocumentCommand]

Comment: Add `\usepackage{xparse}` to your list of packages (before `\RenewDocumentCommand`), or update your TeX distribution; [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) functionality has been added to the distribution since Oct 2020.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you, this works as intended now.